# Proving divisibility in elementary number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers n such that $(n+1)\mid(n^2+1)$.

What I have done so far.

I noticed that $ n^2 + 1 = (n + 1 - 1)^2 + 1 = (n + 1)^2 -2(n + 1) + 2$.
Hence, for the relation to be true, we must have that $(n+1)\mid 2$, that is $n=1$.

How would I prove it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking "why" about - your argument is great!

Comment: I justed wanted to confirm that my argument was correct

Comment: I totally agree with Zev Chonoles. It's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is wonderful.

Why must $n = 1$? Since the only positive integers that divide $2$ are $1$ and $2.$ So the only solution for positive $n$ such that $(n + 1)$ divides $2$ is when for $n = 1 \implies n + 1$. $\;(n = 0$ would given us $n + 1 = 1 \mid 2$, but $n = 0 \ngeq 1$.)

Done!

Of course, you are using the fact that $\,a\mid (am + an + x) \iff a\mid a(m + n) + x \implies a \mid x,\;$ but that is fairly easy discern, given your argument.

Comment: How would I do the proof of this problem?

Comment: You pretty much have a proof! Just fill in your thought process, why $n + 1$ must divide $2$, and why $n$ must then be $1$. You will have eliminated all other cases. Just show the work you did, explain your reasoning (e.g., fill in some of the details I've included above), and you'll have a very good proof.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is very good. There is a very minor flaw. In principle, you should have written that $n+1$ divides $n^2+1$ **if and only if** $n+1$ divides $2$. Since you did not write that, and only wrote the equivalent of "any solution must divide $2$," you should have verified that $n=1$ actually works.

I will describe two other approaches  that are (in this case) less nice than yours.

$1.$ Divide the polynomial $x^2+1$ by $x+1$, in the usual way. We get
$$\frac{x^2}{x+1}= x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}.$$
It follows that for any integer $n\ne -1$, we have
$$\frac{n^2+1}{n+1} =n-1 +\frac{2}{n+1}.$$
Thus $n+1$ divides $n^2+1$ if and only if $n+1$ divides $2$. The only positive solution is $n=1$.

$2.$ We use *congruence* notation. If you have not met it yet, it is coming soon. Note that $n\equiv -1\pmod{n+1}$. It follows that $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{n+1}$. But from $n+1$ divides $n^2+1$, we conclude that $n^2\equiv -1\pmod{n+1}$.

From $n^2\equiv -1\pmod{n+1}$ and $n^2\equiv -1\pmod{n+1}$, we conclude by subtraction that $2\equiv 0\pmod{n+1}$, that is, $n+1$ divides $2$. The only (positive) $n$ that works is given by $n=1$. Finally, if $n=1$, then indeed $n+1$ divides $n^2+1$.